# How do u run a .py file when a button is clicked when using qt Creator

Tags: python, pyqt, qml

I was able to create an interface using `qt Creator` for the frontend of a loan app in Python. Now I want it to separately display or push a display in the stack view which will display a wizard kind of window. I can't seem to make the wizard file which I converted from .ui format run when the button is triggered.

I used the qt designer in the qt creator IDE to create the wizard.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#ffffff"
        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            id: button
            text: qsTr("Button")
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.rightMargin: 0
            anchors.bottomMargin: 0
            onClicked: stackView.push(Qt.resolvedUrl("wizard.py"))
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: rectangle1
            color: "#ffffff"
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: button.top
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            anchors.bottomMargin: 10
            anchors.rightMargin: 10

            StackView {
                id: stackView
                width: 200
                height: 200
                initialItem: Qt.resolvedUrl("homePage.qml")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Throws the following error:

```
traceback >>file://(.py file location) 1 Expected token `numeric literal'
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: don't you get error message when you run code in console/terminal ?  always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not cmment) as text (not screenshot). There are ther useful iformation.

Comment: as usually I would start with `/full/path/to/wizard.py`

Comment: @furas I don't think the StackView can load a python script, I think the OP has an XY problem

Comment: okay...thank u.
but how do I make it display as a separate window when the button is triggered?

Comment: @Richie_Eloh Could you provide what I have asked of you?, please use `@username`

Comment: @Tomerikoo As I already pointed out, the OP does not want to launch a script from another python script, if you check the code provided by the OP it is clearly not python code but QML. The OP somehow wants to load an item implemented in the .py in the StackView item of qml but if he does not provide the MRE it is impossible to help him

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry this is my first time hearing about MRE. Added it to the original post.

Comment: @Richie_Eloh That is not yet an MRE since to reproduce the problem I need main.py and wizard.py(or the .ui file). If you don't provide it then your post will probably be closed